# Flutter error: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, flutter, flutter-layout

So, Heres the code of my student list..I am using sqlflite database to store student collection.. but when i run this.. this shows error in my futurebuilder method . I am getting my error in the snapshot.data.lenght line where the error shows that length should not be null thats why i tried some conditions but still not working

```
class StudentListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StudentListPageState createState() => _StudentListPageState();
}

class _StudentListPageState extends State<StudentListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Student List'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context)=>AddStudentPage()
              ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: DBHelpers.getAllStudent(),
        builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<StudentModels>> snapshot)=>
        snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting?
        Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ):
        Padding(
          child:snapshot.data.length !=0? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index)=>StudentItems(snapshot.data[index])):
          Center(

            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  elevation: 5,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  child: Text("Click me To add Employee", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                  onPressed: (){

                  },
                )
              ],
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That is my database helper code :

```
class DBHelpers{

  static final String CREATE_TABLE=''' create table $TABLE_STUDENT(
  $COL_STUDENT_ID integer primary key autoincrement,
  $COL_STUDENT_NAME text not null,
  $COL_STUDENT_PHONE integer not null,
  $COL_STUDENT_EMAIL text not null,
  $COL_STUDENT_FAVOURITE text )''';

  static Future<Database> open() async{
    final dbpath=await getDatabasesPath();
    final path=Path.join(dbpath,'student.db');
    return openDatabase(path,version: 1,onCreate: (db,version) async{
      db.execute(CREATE_TABLE);
    });
  }

  static Future<int> insertStudent(String table,Map<String,dynamic> map) async{
    final db=await open();
    return db.insert(table, map,conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  static Future<List<StudentModels>> getAllStudent() async{
      final db=await open();
      final List<Map<String,dynamic>> map=await db.query(TABLE_STUDENT,orderBy: COL_STUDENT_NAME);
      return List.generate(map.length, (index){
        return StudentModels.fromMap(map[index]);
      });
  }

}
```

This is my students_model:

```
final String TABLE_STUDENT='tbl_student';
final String COL_STUDENT_ID='col_id';
final String COL_STUDENT_NAME='col_name';
final String COL_STUDENT_EMAIL='col_email';
final String COL_STUDENT_PHONE='col_phone';
final String COL_STUDENT_FAVOURITE='col_fav';

class StudentModels{
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  int phoneNumber;
  bool isFavourite;

  StudentModels({
      this.id, this.name, this.email, this.phoneNumber, this.isFavourite=false
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'StudentModels{id: $id, name: $name, email: $email, phoneNumber: $phoneNumber, isFavourite: $isFavourite}';
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map=<String,dynamic>{
      COL_STUDENT_NAME:name,
      COL_STUDENT_EMAIL:email,
      COL_STUDENT_PHONE:phoneNumber,
      COL_STUDENT_FAVOURITE:isFavourite,
    };
    if(id!=null){
      map[COL_STUDENT_ID]=id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  StudentModels.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    name=map[COL_STUDENT_NAME];
    id=map[COL_STUDENT_ID];
    email=map[COL_STUDENT_EMAIL];
    phoneNumber=map[COL_STUDENT_PHONE];
    isFavourite=map[COL_STUDENT_FAVOURITE];
  }


}
```

And this is the Error that I am getting eaach time i run it:

```
E/SQLiteLog(11830): (1) no such table: tbl_student
I/flutter (11830): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (11830): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<StudentModels>>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (11830): _FutureBuilderState<List<StudentModels>>#1afc9):
I/flutter (11830): The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (11830): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11830): Tried calling: length
I/flutter (11830): 
I/flutter (11830): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (11830):   FutureBuilder<List<StudentModels>>
I/flutter (11830):   file:///D:/flutterapps/first_flutter_app/lib/pages/student_list.dart:29:13
I/flutter (11830): 
I/flutter (11830): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (11830): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
I/flutter (11830): #1      _StudentListPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:first_flutter_app/pages/student_list.dart:37:31)
I/flutter (11830): #2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:732:55)
I/flutter (11830): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
I/flutter (11830): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
I/flutter (11830): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
I/flutter (11830): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
I/flutter (11830): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33)
I/flutter (11830): #8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:20)
I/flutter (11830): #9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter (11830): #10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter (11830): #11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter (11830): #12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter (11830): #16     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter (11830): #17     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter (11830): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (11830): 
I/flutter (11830): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
E/SQLiteLog(11830): (1) no such table: tbl_student

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<StudentModels>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<StudentModels>>#1afc9):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<List<StudentModels>> file:///D:/flutterapps/first_flutter_app/lib/pages/student_list.dart:29:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _StudentListPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:first_flutter_app/pages/student_list.dart:37:31)
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:732:55)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
```

Comment: Incidentally, while it's true that telephone numbers are comprised of digits, it's probably not useful to think of them as integers. It's unlikely that you would want to multiply one by another, for instance, and '089280' is a different phone number from '0089280', or indeed '89280'. Telephone numbers are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this on snapshot recive

```
builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<StudentModels>> snapshot) {
   //progress UI 
  if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
                return Center(child: Circular Progress Indicator());

  //load null data UI 
  if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null)
                return Container();

  //load empty data UI 
  if (snapshot.data.isEmpty)
                return Container();

 //enter your code to show data
 //show the list of student model
...
```

Comment: Thank u , this helped